# What does step 3 of the Flowtype.js instructions mean?

Tags: jquery

Every tutorial I've found about Flowtype.js just rehatches the exact same phrasing, leaving me stuck.

I've done jQuery only in Codecademy, never on a site, and am completely confused by the [Flowtype.js Step 3](http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/#getting-started)

> Step 3: Call FlowType.JS
>   To begin the magic, simply call FlowType.JS before the close of your body tag:
>
> $('body').flowtype();

Do I just put the `$('body').flowtype();` right into the html or should that be separated out into some kind of script? I haven't been able to get it to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a script tag and document ready function...as below. Put this JUST before your closing body tag.

```
<script>

$(function () {
    $('body').flowtype();
});

</script>
```

Comment: Inside of /js/ I have a file `flowtype.js` then in my head I have `<script src='/js/flowtype.jQuery.js'></script>` and finally right before the end of the body tag, I have what you up above. Nothing seems to happen though?

Comment: What console errors do you get? Also, try putting the FULL url in the js src...just want to make sure it's not a directory issue (i.e. you're not calling the file correctly)

Comment: Also, do you have a jQuery script in your head? You'll need that - and the flowtype script needs to be AFTER the jQuery script.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem and did some research, too.
I found the actual solution here:
[Setting up FlowType.js under Wordpress](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/setting-up-flowtypejs)

```
    <script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      $('body').flowtype();
      });    
    </script>

  </body>
```

I have included the `</body>` to show where exactly to call the function